# How do I get probability/confidence as output for a CNN using keras in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So, I'm new to deep learning and I've started with cats and dogs dataset for a CNN Model using Keras.

In my code, I'm unable to get probabilities as output for both `classifier.predict` or `classifier.predict_proba`. I'm just getting the output as `[[0,1]]` or `[[1,0]]`. I've tried with several images.

But I'm looking for something like, `[[0.4,0.6]]`, `[[0.89,0.11]]`

I've tried changing loss function from `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`.

I've tried changing the activation function of the output layer from `sigmoid` to `softmax`.

I've also tried changing the `class_mode` in `flow_from_directory` from `binary` to `categorical`.

*I think I might be going wrong with the data type, as the type of array of output is float32. But even if that is the error, I don't know how to change it though.*

I'm unable to find where I'm going wrong. Please clarify/help. Thanks.

> Why do I need probabilities?
>
> In my another project, I'll be splitting an image into 'n' number of smaller pieces. I'll then use the classifier on 'n' number of pieces separately and find the one piece with the largest probability. For this, I won't use the dataset of cats and dogs though. It's for bin-picking and that dataset will also be binary output as 'YES' or 'NO'. Any suggestions for this is also welcome. Thanks.

[Link](https://github.com/snitch30/cnnkeras_test1/blob/master/testfile.py) for the code in Github.

```
    #Building the CNN
    
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense
    
    #Initialising the CNN
    
    classifier = Sequential()
    
    #Step 1 - Convolution
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=32,kernel_size=[3,3],input_shape=(64,64,3),activation='relu'))
    
    #Step 2 - Pooling
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2))
    
    #Adding another Convolutional Layer for better accuracy
    #classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=32,kernel_size=[3,3],activation='relu'))
    #classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2))
    
    #Step 3 - Flattening
    classifier.add(Flatten()) 
    
    #Step 4 - Fully Connected Layers
    classifier.add(Dense(units= 64, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units= 2, activation='softmax'))
    
    
    #Compiling the CNN
    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    #Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    
    train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1./255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True)
    
    test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                     target_size=(64,64),
                                                     batch_size=32,
                                                     class_mode='categorical')
    
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                                target_size=(64,64),
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode='categorical')
    
    classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch=250,
                        epochs=3,                       #Just for time being I've kept very few epochs.
                        validation_data=test_set,
                        validation_steps=62)
    
    
    #Making new Predictions
    import numpy as np
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    
    test_image_luna=image.load_img('dataset/single/SkilletLuna.JPG',target_size=(64,64))
    test_image2=image.img_to_array(test_image_luna)
    test_image2=np.expand_dims(test_image2,axis=0)
    luna=classifier.predict_proba(test_image2)

In [11]: luna
    ...: 
Out[11]: array([[0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Did you check the accuracy of the predictions? Did the NN learn at least something?

Comment: Yeah, it did learn. It has 50% accuracy with 1 epoch. 80% accuracy with 25 epochs. It classifies without issues, only thing is it should give me some decimal values for at least some images (when I use classifer.predict) and it doesn't, which bothers me. @markuscosinus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the mistake. You are rescaling your train and test data with the `ImageDataGenerator`. But you are not doing that when testing a single image.
Try this:

```
# Making new Predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

test_image_luna = image.load_img('D:\\NR\\data\\live2013\\caps.bmp', target_size=(64,64))
test_image2 = image.img_to_array(test_image_luna)/255.
test_image2 = np.expand_dims(test_image2, axis=0)
luna = classifier.predict_proba(test_image2)
```

The high input values lead to very high output values. Since you are using softmax activation these values are leading to predictions very close to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for something like, [[0.4,0.6]], [[0.89,0.11]]

`classifier.predict` is the method you should use to get probabilities. Could you check again, considering the following tips?

There are two ways to build a binary classifier:

1. NN with **one output neuron** with **sigmoid activation**. The output `a` is interpreted as the probability for class 1, thus the probability for class 2 is `1-a`.
2. NN with **two output neurons** using **softmax activation**. Each neuron is then interpreted as the probability of one class.

Both are valid options, but since you are doing 2. you should use softmax activation.

> I've tried changing loss function from binary_crossentropy to
>   categorical_crossentropy.

This should not make a difference, it's basically the same formula.

> I think I might be going wrong with the data type, as the type of
>   array of output is float32. But even if that is the error, I don't
>   know how to change it though.

This is also not the cause of the error, since the type `float32` is right for probability outputs.

Comment: Yeah, I agree classifier.predict should give a probability, but somehow it is rounding itself to either 0 or 1 with the above code. 
Also, I tried with 1 output neuron for sigmoid and 2 for softmax, the result for both is a rounded output of 0 or 1. I don't think the classifier is that confident. Moreover, to tackle this I even tried running fewer epochs (like 1 or 3) to get probabilities in decimals, but it only gives out 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Either predict() or predict_generator() would work.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

test_image_luna=image.load_img('dataset/single/SkilletLuna.JPG',target_size=(64,64))
test_image2=image.img_to_array(test_image_luna)
test_image2=np.expand_dims(test_image2,axis=0)
luna=classifier.predict(test_image2)

print(luna)
```

If you'd want prediction probabilities on 'n' images (or 'n' subsets of an image as in your case), you could try predict_generator():

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                             target_size=(64,64),
                                             batch_size=32,
                                             class_mode='categorical')

predicted_probabilities = classifier.predict_generator(test_set)
print(predicted_probabilities)
```

Use the following to print in percentage rounded to 2 decimal places:

```
print(np.round(luna*100,2))
print(np.round(predicted_probabilities*100,2))
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the predict_generator to predict n images simultaneously. 
Yeah, I agree classifier.predict should work, but somehow it is rounding itself to either 0 or 1 with the above code. 
Also, I tried with 1 output neuron for sigmoid and 2 for softmax, the result for both is a rounded output of 0 or 1. I don't think the classifier is that confident. Moreover, to tackle this I even tried running fewer epochs (like 1 or 3) to get probabilities in decimals, but it only gives out 0 or 1.

Comment: You could include this at the top of your code: `np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=False)`. I think it's an array formatting issue. Softmax function and epochs seem good!

Comment: Yeah, it was an array formatting issue, I hadn't rescaled the arrays of single test data.

Comment: @Snitch30 How did you solve this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace anywhere that it says activation='relu' or activation='softmax' with activation='sigmoid'. Sigmoid returns a value between 0 to 1 representing confidence, relu/softmax will only return 1 for the most likely answer and 0 for everything else.

Comment: It is not advisable to replace the hidden layer activation function from `relu` to `sigmoid` function because it may result with the [vanishing gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem). Moreover, `relu` is computationally more efficient. If you replace the `softmax` function in the last layer with `sigmoid`, you can not have [Multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification)