# The output from CNN model is either 1.0 or 0.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

As the heading implies, the output of prediction is either 1.0 or 0.0 and I am not getting any values in between which is causing my outputs to be either 100% fall or 100% nonfall.

```
for img in imagesList:
    test_image = image.load_img(path+img, target_size=(64, 64))
    test_images = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_images = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = classifier.predict(test_images)
    if result[0][0] <= 0.0:
      prediction = 'fall'

      print('The file is:{} while model output is: {}{} {} '.format(img[:-4],((1-result[0][0])*100),'%',prediction))
      print(result[0][0])
      #print('The file is:{} while model output is: {}{} {}'.format(img[:-4],((result[0][0])*100),'%',' nonfall'))
    else:
      prediction = 'nonfall'
      print('The file is:{} while model output is: {}{} {} '.format(img[:-4],((result[0][0])*100),'%',prediction))
      print(result[0][0])
```

Comment: How `classifier` is defined ?

Comment: classifier is the cnn model.

Answer (score 0):

In each `for` loop iteration, you are getting single image and the prediction of it is either category. If you want accuracy over a batch then you need to append images of a batch and then predict. Code should look something like this.

```
image_batch = []

for img in imagesList:
    test_image = image.load_img(path+img, target_size=(64, 64))
    test_images = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_images = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    image_batch.append(np.array(test_images))

result = classifier.predict(image_batch)
```

Comment: if you don't mind could you please elaborate a bit more? I am new to CNN. In many examples they print "This image is 90% class A" and they get probability values(from "result") for the image while I am getting only class label as output.Also when i use predict(image_batch) it throws:
```
Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 14 input tensors.
```

Comment: I know you got your answer. For more details on CNN, this [fashion_mnist](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) would help you understand things better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

I solved the problem by using `model.predict_prob(img)`.

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54532343/13467194